# Parseo web con chrome y vb.net

Tags: vb.net, chrome

¿Hay alguna forma de parsear una web (por ejemplo una web de resultados de partidos para obtener sus resultados) en vb.net usando un navegador diferente a IE?

Yo hasta ahora he usado la librería "Interop.SHDocVw" y me funcionaba el programa pero al ejecutar el programa hace unos días no obtuve valores. Comprobé que viendo la página con IE no me mostraba los valores pero con chrome si me los mostraba.

¿A alguien se le ocurre alguna solución?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si te han cambiado la forma de renderizar los datos tendrás que ir viendo cómo adaptarte, lo mas seguro es que estén usando javascript con alguna librería no compatible con IE (esta sospecha es pues dices que se ve en chrome y no en IE)

Específico de VB no conozco un reemplazo del "SHDocVw" que es el motor Trident de IE, en cuanto a un reemplazo del mismo estilo para EDGE no sería tarea sencilla pues [no soporta COM/Activex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40457886/1423096)

En principio podes analizar el documento que te entrega el "SHDocVw" y ver si los datos que antes estaban en html son cargados o generados dinámicamente y tratar de recuperar ese recurso (ej. si hay un load resultados.js por algún lado)

Otra opción es probar de integrar en tu app el motor chromium de chrome.
Un wrapper .net de chromium es por ejemplo [CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp), (la app windows facebook gameroom lo usa como navegador incrustado)

Hay algunas pistas de cómo hacerlo en https://stackoverflow.com/q/27454471/1423096

Dentro del ecosistema .net también hay proyectos interesantes del tipo https://github.com/kblok/puppeteer-sharp que usa headless chrome.

Pero ahí ya estarías entrando en otro terreno mas complejo (headless chrome corre en otro proceso y con puppeteer lo vas controlando)

**Y por último pero no menos importante:** consulta en la web que estás accediendo si tienen un api para recuperar esos resultados. Si es para uso personal y no entra en conflicto con su modelo de negocios seguramente te puedan orientar mejor.

Comment: Muchas gracias. A ver si tengo algún rato y me puedo poner a probar lo que me has sugerido